# implement one RNN layer in deep DAE seems worse performance

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying to implement one RNN layer in deep DAE which is shown in the figure:

DRDAE:

[image]

My code is modified based on the DAE tutorial, I change one layer to basic LSTM RNN layer. It somehow can works. The noise in output among different pictures seems lies in same places.

However, compared to both only one layer of RNN and the DAE tutorial, the performance of the structure is much worse. And it requires much more iteration to reach a lower cost.

Can someone help why does the structure got worse result? Below is my code for DRDAE.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 50001
batch_size = 256
display_step = 500
examples_to_show = 10
total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)

# Network Parameters
n_input = 784 # data input
n_hidden_1 = 392 # 1st layer num features
n_hidden_2 = 196 # 2nd layer num features
n_steps = 14

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])

weights = {
    'encoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'encoder_h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'decoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_input])),
}
biases = {
    'encoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'encoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'decoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input])),
}

def RNN(x, size, weights, biases):

    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'n_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    # Unstack to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    x = tf.split(x,n_steps,1)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(size, forget_bias=1.0)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + biases

# Building the encoder
def encoder(x):
    # Encoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #1
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['encoder_h1']), biases['encoder_b1']))
    # Decoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #2
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['encoder_h2']), biases['encoder_b2']))
    return layer_2

# Building the decoder
def decoder(x):
    # Encoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #1
    layer_1 = RNN(x, n_hidden_2, weights['decoder_h1'],biases['decoder_b1'])
    # Decoder Hidden layer with sigmoid activation #2
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['decoder_h2']), biases['decoder_b2']))
    return layer_2

# Construct model
encoder_op = encoder(X)
decoder_op = decoder(encoder_op)

# Prediction
y_pred = decoder_op
# Targets (Labels) are the original data.
y_true = Y

# Define loss and optimizer, minimize the squared error
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_true - y_pred, 2))
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_pred,1), tf.argmax(y_true,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    sess.run(init)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch, _ = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            origin = batch
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: batch, Y: origin})
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            c, acy = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch, Y: origin})
            print("Epoch:", '%05d' % (epoch+1), "cost =", "{:.9f}".format(c), "accuracy =", "{:.3f}".format(acy))
    print("Optimization Finished!")

     # Applying encode and decode over test set
    encode_decode = sess.run(
        y_pred, feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images[:examples_to_show]})
    # Compare original images with their reconstructions
    f, a = plt.subplots(2, 10, figsize=(10, 2))
    for i in range(examples_to_show):
        a[0][i].imshow(np.reshape(mnist.test.images[i], (28, 28)))
        a[1][i].imshow(np.reshape(encode_decode[i], (28, 28)))
```